# Imprimir mensagem na próxima pagina

Tags: cakephp

Como faço para imprimir uma mensagem ao abrir uma página, por exemplo:

Estou na pagina `Cliente/View` e ao ser redirecionado para a página `Nfe/index`, quero que seja impresso uma mensagem com instruções sobre o que deve ser feito, puxando alguns dados da `Cliente/View`.

Tentei usar o

```
$this->Session->setFlash('mensagem');
```

Mas continuei sem resultados, só é exibido a mensagem quando eu volto para a página `Cliente/View` novamente.

Answer (score 0):

Para este mesmo caso, a seguinte [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765692/cakephp-show-flash-messages-at-different-positions-in-the-view-page) me ajudou, veja ela abaixo:

Ao usar o [setFlash](http://api.cakephp.org/class/session-component#method-SessionComponentsetFlash), você poderá fornecer um valor chave, por exemplo:

```
$this->Session->setFlash('This message is for form 1.', 'default', array(), 'form1');
```

Então você pode imprimir o flash acima de cada formulário. Ele só será exibido se a chave especificada tiver um valor.

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('form1') ?>
```

Para mais informações consulte [Criando Mensagem de Notificação](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#creating-notification-messages).

Comment: Cara eu testei aqui e só funciona se ele tiver na mesma `controller`, se a `View` estiver em `controller` diferente, isso não funciona.